# Problem with Maps in java

Tags: java, collections, hashmap

I have a Hashmap which has X number of elements
I need to move this map into another map
This is what my code looks like

```
Map originMap = initialize();
Map destMap = new Hashmap ();  

int originMapSize = originMap.size(); 
Set<Map.Entry<K, V>> entries = originMap.entrySet();
for (Map.Entry<K, Y> mapEntry : entries) {
 K key = mapEntry.getKey();
 V value = mapEntry.getValue();
 destMap.put (key,value);
}  

// Shouldnt this be equal to originMapSize ????
int destMapSize = destMap.size();
```

What I am observing is - originMapSize is NOT equal to the destMapSize

It seems when we put the elements in the destMap, some of the elements are being overridden

We have overrridden the hashCode and equals method- and it is a suspicious implementation.
However, if the originMap allowed the elements to be added, why would the destinationMap not add a new elements and override an existing element instead ?

Comment: What does the initialize method do and why is `i++` in there?

Comment: How are you initializing the "entries" variable being iterated through in your for loop?

Comment: If a key already exists in the map then it will override the previous value.

Comment: i++ was for debugging purpose only. removed it now.

Comment: @Varun: My question is- why did the first map allow two keys to exist together and second map is overriding it

Comment: What happens when you use the `putAll` method instead?

Comment: @RN - That can be ascertained only after looking at your hashCode method.

Comment: You could avoid equals/hashcode altogether if you could use IdentityHashMap

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This could happen if the `equals` method was asymmetric. Suppose there are two keys a and b such that:

- `a.hashCode() == b.hashCode()`
- `a.equals(b)` returns false
- `b.equals(a)` returns true

Then suppose that the `HashMap` implementation searches for an existing key by calling `existingKey.equals(newKey)` for each existing key with the same hash code as the new key.

Now suppose we originally add them in the order { a, b }.

The first key (`a`) obviously goes in with no problems. The second key (`b`) insertion ends up calling `a.equals(b)` - which is false, so we get two keys.

Now building the second `HashMap`, we may end up getting the entries in the order { b, a }.

This time we add `b` first, which is fine... but when we insert the second key (`a`) we end up calling `b.equals(a)`, which returns true, so we *overwrite* the entry.

That may not be what's going on, but it *could* explain things - and shows the dangers of an asymmetric `equals` method.

EDIT: Here's a short but complete program demonstrating this situation. (The exact details of `a` and `b` may not be the same, but the asymmetry is.)

```
import java.util.*;

public class Test {

    private final String name;

    public Test(String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Map<Test, String> firstMap = new HashMap<Test, String>();

        Test a = new Test("a");
        Test b = new Test("b");

        firstMap.put(b, "b");
        firstMap.put(a, "a");

        Map<Test, String> secondMap = new HashMap<Test, String>();
        for (Map.Entry<Test, String> entry : firstMap.entrySet())
        {
            System.out.println("Adding " + entry.getKey().name);
            secondMap.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
        }
        System.out.println(secondMap.size());
    }

    @Override public int hashCode()
    {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override public boolean equals(Object other)
    {
        return this.name.equals("b");
    }
}
```

Output on my machine:

```
Adding a
Adding b
1
```

You may not get the output that way round - it depends on:

- The way that `equals` is called (`candidateKey.equals(newKey)` or vice versa)
- The order in which entries are returned from the set

It may even work differently on different runs.

Comment: how does one go about creating an asymetric equals function?

Comment: hmmmm. I see what you mean. Would using a the multimap from Guava library *help*  (If I didn't want to change the equals\hashcode right now)

Comment: @RN: Not sure. But if you've got a bad equals/hashCode implementation, fixing that should be your #1 priority - until you've done that you *will* see weird stuff.

Comment: Just verified - the equals method is asymmetric . Thanks this was very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Those values should be equal, but the problem is you are iterating over a different Map object.

```
for (Map.Entry mapEntry : entries)
```

is not the same as

```
for (Map.Entry mapEntry : originMap)
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure he meant originMap.entrySet().

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the order of the elements being added to the first hashmap is not the same as the order added to the second. This combined with the sketchy hashCode method is causing duplicates to be added to the first.

Try changing hashCode to always return the same value to see if your problem goes away.

Comment: I don't think a bad `hashCode` implementation would cause this, but a bad `equals` implementation certainly can - see my answer for an example.

Comment: You are probably right, but since hashCode is only a performance tweak, I would remove it when debugging an issue like this.

Comment: By "remove it", do you mean remove the override? That will change the behaviour completely, because you will end up with objects which may return `true` from `equals` but have different hash codes. You *could* make it just return 0... but I don't think that's going to be the problem here.

Comment: Yes, I would just return 0. In fact I would always do that until I identified a performance problem.

Comment: Wow, really? It's pretty easy to get hash codes right in most situations (just follow Effective Java) - why would you want to turn every HashMap lookup into an O(n) operation? I'm all for avoiding micro-optimizing, but this is an O(1) to O(n) change, all for the sake of not writing what is normally a pretty simple method.

Comment: Well, I may be exagerating my point a bit, but in reality I find I rarely need to implement the hc/equals pair. It's usually strings that serve as hashmap keys, or I just use an IdentityHashMap. I often find that the notion of equality is context specific, so I've learned to just avoid thr hc/equals contract

Comment: Sure, I only implement it when I need it - but that's not the same as implementing it *badly*. It's unfortunate that Java doesn't have an equivalent of the .NET `IEqualityComparer<T>` interface, which does for equality what `Comparator<T>` does for ordering in Java. All the various hash-based collections (`HashSet`, `Dictionary` etc) allow you to specify a custom comparer. Very handy.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use destMap.putAll(originMap) ?

Answer (score 0):

Map has a *putAll* method.   Try something like this:

```
    Map<String, String> destination = new HashMap<String, String>();
    Map<String, String> original = new HashMap<String, String>();

    destination.putAll(original);
```

Comment: Same result. The size of the second map is different.

Answer (score 0):

It depends of how the first HashMap is initialized. Also everytime you add an object into the HashMap , once it passes 75% load factor, it allocates twice the default size to accomodate new values. Maps usually have default size = 16: when you pass the 75% load factor it enlarges to 32.